# IndexError: tuple index out of range in my Keras model.fit_generator

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am completely new to Keras/Tensorflow. Below is my fit_generator

```
train_dataset=train_fn_inputs(batch_size, None) 
val_data=validation_fn_inputs(batch_size, None) 
total_records = 44712  
val_records = 11178  
steps_per_epoch=int(total_records // batch_size)

hist=model.fit_generator(#aug.flow(X_def, y_def, batch_size=batch_size), 
               #get_batches(X_def, y_def, batch_size), 
               train_dataset,
               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, #(training_df.shape[0])//batchsize,
               epochs=5,
               verbose = 1,
               #callbacks=[early_stopping],
               #validation_data=val_data, 
               #validation_steps=val_records//batch_size,
               workers=0
          )
```

And the function definitions are:

```
def train_fn_inputs(bs,  aug=None):
    train_files, total_records = get_training_data_old()
    steps_per_epoch = int(total_records / batch_size)    
    raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(train_files)     #.repeat()
    parsed_image_dataset = raw_dataset.map(_parse_image_function).repeat().shuffle(buffer_size=buf_size).batch(batch_size).make_initializable_iterator()  

    image, label = parsed_image_dataset.get_next()
    image = tf.reshape(image, [3, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, bs])
    #label = tf.reshape(label, [bs, 75, 25])

    while True:
       yield (np.array(image), np.array(label))
```

But am getting this error:

> File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 184, in model_iteration
>       batch_size = int(nest.flatten(batch_data)[0].shape[0])
>
> IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If not, please share the complete reproducible code so that I can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I have solved the problem.